# Other Calendars in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

i am new to Google Calendars i didn't never i logged in google Calendars .there are two Categories of Calendars 
1. My Calendars
2. Other Calendar

in other Calendar it is showing two calendars by default one is Indian Holidays and second is Contact's birthday can i add events to these calendars because right now when i select only Indian Holidays and create event in that event when i click it is showing calendar as my default calendar and when i use api and specify the calendar id as en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com
and specify parameters then it is not creating events in that calendar but instead in my default calendar when i call using calendar api .i am getting error NOT Found .can any one please specify is it possible to create Events in category Other Calendar

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have permissions to write in that calendar?
You can check it by going to the [UI](http://calendar.google.com) and clicking on any empty slot, you will be presented a window, showing "What", "When" and "Calendar" options; open de "Calendar" select box and try to find the "Indian Holidays" option, if you don't see it, then you are not allowed to write and that's why you can't do it by an API call

Hope this helps, regards